# While working with spring boot and reactive programming, I saw actor-tcp-nio in console. What does it mean?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rx-java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I created a spring boot application using web flux. I logged my results in console. I saw that my method I created using Mono is executing on parallel-1 thread but I saw this `actor-tcp-nio-1` in which methods of Mono are executing. What is this thread? Why doesn't it execute on parallel-1 thread.

console log

```
2021-04-04 23:27:04.356  INFO 7225 --- [     parallel-1] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onSubscribe(FluxUsingWhen.UsingWhenSubscriber)
2021-04-04 23:27:04.357  INFO 7225 --- [     parallel-1] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : request(unbounded)
2021-04-04 23:27:09.730  INFO 7225 --- [actor-tcp-nio-1] reactor.Flux.UsingWhen.1                 : onNext(
```

Comment: That's a reactor-netty thread. The logger chops down the beginning of its name.

Answer (score 2):

When executing a reactive chain, the thread is not guaranteed to remain the same for the entire execution. The execution thread will change depending on different operations defined in the chain, e.g. `subscribeOn()` and `publishOn()` to name a few.
By the name of it, I believe it's an RSocket library thread, whereas `parallel-x` is from a Reactor threadpool.